# JavaScript style property is empty

Tags: javascript, css, dom, properties

I need to calculate the width of an element's border.  If I set it explicitly (via CSS), then I can access it in JavaScript by:

```
    element.style.borderWidth
```

However, if *only* specify border style property (and not 'border-width') ->

```
    border-style: solid
```

Then the `borderWidth` property is empty. Why? My approach to calculate width is as follows:

```
if(element.style.borderWidth == ''){
    borderWidth = (offsetHeight - clientHeight)/2
}
```

Is there any other way to calculate border width whilst only setting `border-style`?

Comment: What you are looking for is the *computed style* of the element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `window.getComputedStyle` for modern browsers

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).borderBottomWidth;
```

---

For IE pre-9 you will have to use an alternative

```
element.currentStyle.borderBottomWidth
```